# Ubuntu NFS Client connecting to Windows 2008 R2 NFS share - permissions issue

Tags: windows, nfs, ubuntu-12.04

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS x64 trying to connect to NFS share on Windows 2008 R2 server - which is a domain member server. I can mount the share in Ubuntu but if I try to ls the mount folder I get 'permission denied' message, that is unless I give 'Everyone' permissions to the shared windows folder, when I can then access the files just fine - so it looks like windows user mapping is not working.

I have NFS Server in windows configured for NFS v3 and the Identity Mapping source to use my AD domain. I am trying to get user mapping via my AD user account which is configured with uidNumber and gidNumber for my Ubuntu user (1000).

When creating the NFS share in windows I have enabled 'Auth_Sys' authentication method. To be honest, I tried all the authentication methods available with no joy either. I also allowed read-write access to my Ubuntu client by hostname (which is resolvable in dns to correct IP). In windows the folder which is shared has my Windows user in the ACL with full control permissions.

In my mind, when accessing the mounted share folder in Linux, my uid/gid should be passed to NFS server in Windows, which should line up with my windows user to get full control permissions to the shared folder. This doesn't appear to work.

Anyone any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Paul A